# Grocerycrud: Read, Edit and Delete operations won't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Hi I've been testing Grocerycrud on my hosting server, but there's a couple of issues I've been facing and I've been pulling my hair for hours.

The one thing I can´t get is why I can't perform the **READ**, **EDIT** and **DELETE** operations, I get all the parameters apparently being passed to the URL, but **NO FORM** is displayed and when it comes to **DELETING** records, the selected record **IS NOT** deleted after I click yes on the JavaScript alert displayed by the browser.

***Is it something related to the set_crud_url_path function?***

**I have tested Grocerycrud on my local server and it all worked perfect! so I don't get why is not working on my hosting server.**

Here's an image caption of my COSTUMERS TABLE and the URL parameters being passed after I clicked edit, but no form is showed.

[Caption of "Edit" operation not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY9s7.png)

***Versions:***

> - PHP 5.3.29
> - Codeigniter 2.1.4
> - Web server running: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) mod_hive/5.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
> - GroceryCRUD 1.5.4

I really hope you can help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

As you can see in my image there's a **.php** file extension after the name of the file being called, that was affecting the operations since there should not be no file extensions.

Just set the url_suffix empty: $config['url_suffix'] = ''; in CI's application/config/**config.php** and now all operations are executed properly.